# Different ways / designs to scrape blog sites

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl all blog sites for specific fields. For eg. title, description, tags, date, author etc. I am using scrapy library build in python.

Now for each site html is going to be different. I won't always get title in h1 tag. Every blog site has different format. I do not have fixed number of sites that I want to crawl. Also I do not want to change code every time when I want to scrape new site.

What best practices / design patterns I should follow to make sure I end up in less problems / challenges. I can use Factory pattern which end up in a different class for each site. I don't want to do that as it again requires developer involvement.

I am looking for solution which can reduce human involvement.

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. There are a lot of ways to find and extract specific attributes from html like headers, article body, dates etc. You should look into and/or open up a question for every one of those individually.

Comment: So I am here talking about only body. I am interested in HTML body. And within HTML body each website will have different HTML structure. Its very hard to define common pattern but I am looking for best practice so that I can end up with scalable and maintainable approach.

Comment: This question is still far too broad as the exact *best* mechanism for extracting content like that will likely depend on each actual site.

Comment: Yes it will depend on each actual site but my question is not how but what are best practices around it. I think you did not get it.

Answer (score 2):

There are quie few packages that do this, most of them are just clever algorithms around lxml though. Most known is probably [newspaper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/newspaper) which is designed for articles but it works with blogpost etc. pretty well too.

For scrapy you'd probably want to ditch the download mechanism newspaper uses to use asynchronious scrapy downloader.

Comment: This is really awesome library. I am trying with multiple sites. What I likes about this library is, it also supports nlp. Next step which is in my pipeline. I am going to try with at least 5 different blog sites which are having very different structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a Factory pattern but in terms of reducing human effort to set up and maintain an environment, you might want to check out https://scrapinghub.com/scrapy-cloud/ as a place to host, run and manage different spiders

Practically, in terms of reducing rewrite effort I've learnt that I usually have one or two navigation pieces of code plus a third data collection definition

1. For handling javascript elements such as "Show more" type javascript buttons
2. For navigating links to open to collect information
3. A series of items (in scrapy) which are common across all the fields I'm looking for - I just copy and paste this section and adjust the xpaths appropriate for each site to look for where the data is contained

This helps me reduce rewrite effort for collecting similar data across different sites.

This way, most of the time is spent on working out how best to navigate and then tailor the xpaths for data collection rather than having to completely rewrite every time.

Hope that helped somewhat...